# AngualrJS not invoking the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

My state state.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').config(stateConfig);

    stateConfig.$inject = [ '$stateProvider' ];

    function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('bmc', {
          parent : 'entity',
          url : '/bmc',
          data : {
            authorities : [ 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN' ],
          },
          views : {
              'content@' : {
                templateUrl : 'bmc.html',
                controller : 'BmcController',
                controllerAs : 'vm'
              }
          }
        }).state('list', {
          parent : 'bmc',
          url : '/list/:routeId/:entity',
          data : {
              authorities : [ 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER' ],
          },
          views : {
              'fieldContent@' : {
                templateUrl : 'list.html',
                controller : 'ListController',
                controllerAs : 'vm'
              }
          },
          resolve : {
            loadMyFiles : function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                  name : 'list',
                  files : [ 'crud.service.js', 'list.controller.js' ]
                })
            },
            translatePartialLoader : [ '$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {

                return $translate.refresh();
            } ]
          }
        });
    }
})();
```

list.controller.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('ListController', ListController);

    ListController.$inject = [ '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams' ];

    function ListController($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;

        console.log( $stateParams.entity );
    console.log( $stateParams.routeId );
    }
})();
```

when i click the following url `http://localhost:8080/#/bmc/list/xyz/abc`  generated by the `HTML code` nothing happens. I am not sure where is the problem because i was expecting my `ListController` will be invoked on clicking.

bmc.html

```
<a ui-sref="list({routeId: node.name, entity: entity.name})">{{entity.name}} </a>
```

Comment: My guess would be that something in the resolve section may never be resolving. The controller cannot be created until those values are resolved. Try commenting them out for now and/or adding some log messages.

Comment: I see.. okay let me try.

Comment: I put those js filed directly in the index.html in case but still no action. I think i am doing something very wrong.

Comment: Put a `.then()` handler onto the `$ocLazyLoad.load()` and log both success and failure cases. My guess is that it is failing which will prevent angular transitioning to the `list` state. Also in your `$rootScope` you should watch for the `$stateChangeError` event as that will tell you if there was a problem switching to the desired state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one of the `resolve` values is failing. You should watch for the `$stateChangeError` in your `$rootScope` to be sure you handle these cases. See the ui-router documentation:

> $stateChangeError - fired when an error occurs during transition. It's
>   important to note that if you have any errors in your resolve
>   functions (javascript errors, non-existent services, etc) they will
>   not throw traditionally. You must listen for this $stateChangeError
>   event to catch ALL errors. Use event.preventDefault() to prevent the
>   $UrlRouter from reverting the URL to the previous valid location (in
>   case of a URL navigation).

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 
 function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){ ...
})
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. It was some problem in resolve section with translation. I removed it and seems to be fine. One more thing i noticed and would like to have your opinion. I would like to have my list section inside my bmc section but only for a specific section and not wholly . Thr problem i see the controller may not be loading because the dom was loaded may be after the bmc section so inner list controller dont work. What do you think? as you can see my 'list' views contains name fieldContent@ which is present in bmc.html

Comment: I think that probably needs to be a separate question.